# Preg_Match_All and RegEx Getting Values

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get the 2 values in this string using regex:

```
a:2:{i:45;s:29:"Program Name 1";i:590;s:19:"Program Name 2";}
```

There are 2 variables that start with "s:" and end with ":" which I am attempting to get from this string (and similar strings.

```
$string = 'a:2:{i:45;s:29:"Program Name 1";i:590;s:19:"Program Name 2";}';
preg_match_all("/s:(\d+):/si", $page['perfarray'], $match);
print_r($match);
```

I have tried numerous things but this is the first time I've attempted to use regex to get multiple values from a string.

This is the current result:  Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )

Any constructive help is greatly appreciated.  I have already read the functions on php.net and I can't find a similar question on stack overflow that matches my needs closely enough.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you just unserialize it?

Comment: **Don't use regexes to deal with structured data.**  Unserialize it and use the proper structure.

Comment: It is non-unserializeable though. http://ideone.com/N10k22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a serialized string. Instead of using a regular expression, use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) to retrieve the required value.

Update: It looks like your string is not a valid serialized string. In that case, you *can* use a regular expression to get the job done:

```
$string = 'a:2:{i:45;s:29:"Program Name 1";i:590;s:19:"Program Name 2";}';
if(preg_match_all("/s:(\d+):/si", $string, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 29
    [1] => 19
)
```

Comment: The OP's example is not a valid serialized string. `unserialize()` will not work with it.

Comment: @NotJay: Glad to have been of help. Good luck with your project! :)

Answer (score 2):

That should work:

```
preg_match_all("/s:([0-9]+):/si", $page['perfarray'], $match);
```

Comment: For some odd reason, it isn't working...  The array is still empty.

Comment: @NotJay: Are you not getting [this output](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20381345/1438393)?

Comment: No, I'm not getting that out put yet.  I am trying this on a query result so I will try again with the example string.